# Where is the login page in the lift example app "lift_25_sbt/lift_basic" coming from?

Tags: scala, lift

Lift has some example projects that can be found here

https://github.com/lift/lift_25_sbt/tree/master/scala_29/lift_basic

[image]

Where is the page

```
http://localhost:8080/user_mgt/login
```

coming from?  I do not see any html for this or any code.  It appears to be some sort of baked-in page.  How do you build your own login page or change this one?

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I know nothing about `Lift`.

Path `/login` is from [here](https://github.com/lift/lift_25_sbt/blob/master/scala_29/lift_basic/src/main/scala/bootstrap/liftweb/Boot.scala#L46):

```
def sitemap = SiteMap(
  Menu.i("Home") / "index" >> User.AddUserMenusAfter,
```

Method `AddUserMenusAfter` is from [`MetaMegaProtoUser`](http://liftweb.net/api/25/api/#net.liftweb.mapper.MetaMegaProtoUser). See `User` [implementation](https://github.com/lift/lift_25_sbt/blob/master/scala_29/lift_basic/src/main/scala/code/model/User.scala#L11):

```
object User extends User with MetaMegaProtoUser[User] {
```

To change login page template you should override `loginMenuLocParams`. Example from [discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/liftweb/WFoarHQINXY/ltMgfkPniJQJ) in liftweb group:

```
override protected def loginMenuLocParams: List[LocParam[Unit]] =
  If(notLoggedIn_? _, S.??("already.logged.in")) ::
  Template(() => /// return the template to your login page here) ::
  Nil
```